# Is sci-hub also used in places having institutional access?

Tags: journals, digital-libraries, sci-hub

Has there a study been done regarding the issue? Because I've seen a lot of people directly pasting the doi at scihub without even checking if our institution library wifi has access to the particular journal (even when they are right in the lib).

Comment: [Who's downloading pirated papers?
EVERYONE](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/04/whos-downloading-pirated-papers-everyone)

Comment: SciHub avoids having to battle with ReadCube's "interactive" PDFs.

Comment: I imagine some people might try Scihub first because it avoids the need to grapple with the various paywall and access management systems that legitimate users have to deal with. As is often the case, the pirated version works better.

Comment: I use it when the journal's website is down.

Comment: Yes. it is used by everyone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only study that I'm aware of is the [magazine article that Orion linked to in the comments](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/04/whos-downloading-pirated-papers-everyone). Anecdotally, however, my experience matches yours -- even in places with institutional access, some people prefer sci-hub as it's quicker and easier. No need for a lab-specific login or password, no need to check if the journal is actually one that your institution subscribes to; just paste in the DOI and go. In fact, there are even web browser extensions that automatically append the sci-hub URL to the page you're visiting, so with a few keypresses you can be automatically forwarded to sci-hub's cache of that page.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, as [this 2016 case study](https://im2punt0.wordpress.com/2016/06/20/sci-hub-access-or-convenience-a-utrecht-case-study-part-2/) from Utrecht University points out.

It found that 75% of Utrecht Sci-hub downloads would've been available through existing subscriptions or open-access alternatives.
This is a very interesting discovery, and thankfully today there are more PDF discovery tools available.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE and thank you for your answer. While it is generally fine to recommend your own product as long as your disclose your affiliation, it [also needs to be relevant to answer the question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Here the question was solely about the existence of the phenomenon, not how to avoid it. I have therefore reduced your question to what answers the question.

Comment: Thank you, @Wrzlprmft, I apprecite it.